# MySQL two conditions for two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query:

```
$query5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE (`id`='$switch' AND `rand`='$randID' AND `email`!='".$_SESSION['user']."') ");
```

And second:

```
$query5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pages_admin` WHERE (`pId`='$switch' AND `rand`='$randID' AND `admin`!='".$_SESSION['user']."') ");
```

I use a while loop to present data.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query5)) {}
```

I need one mysql query instead two.

Comment: So you want to combine the two result sets?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @ShreyasChavan is right. If you intend to use this anywhere publicly accessible you should look in to prepared statements using something like mysqli.

Comment: It's easy even you can achive it with `Inner Join` by joining both tables with little bit research and effort also please follow the @hobenkr comment.

Comment: Thanks for info. Currently it will be a small social network. In the future I wanna start learn PDO or MySqLi to create better protected websites.

Answer (score 0):

If these tables are related you can JOIN them using the foreign key.
If I'm not mistaken this pId in the table pages_admin is a foreign key to the id on the table pages, is that correct?

If so, you could do something like this to you query:

```
"SELECT * FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN admin_pages ap on p.id = ap.pId 
WHERE (`pId`=$switch AND `rand`=$randID AND `admin`!='{$_SESSION['user']}')"
```

Note that I've changed the syntax, instead of merging string you can use only one containing all variables you need.